Can we store Regex pattern in gitlab-ci variables?
I'm attempting to configure a simple gitlab-ci files.
Here's the code:
variables:
  SEMVER_REGEX: '/^v?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/'

include:
  - local: ci/dev.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ $SEMVER_REGEX'
  - local: ci/staging.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ $SEMVER_REGEX'
  - local: ci/prod.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ $SEMVER_REGEX'

This doesn't function as expected: the "dev" jobs are always initiated, even with tags, while the prod and staging jobs are never launched. However, if I remove the variable, it works as expected (in a less elegant manner).
include:
  - local: ci/dev.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ /^v?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/'
  - local: ci/staging.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/'
  - local: ci/prod.yaml
    rules:
      - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v?(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$/'

What am I doing wrong?
(I'm on Gitlab v16.9.2)

Can you provide an exemple of match value for regex ?

Did you try $CI_COMMIT_TAG !~ $SEMVER_REGEX
